# The probability that the 3rd coordinate of a random point from the sphere is closer to the center than the poles.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If we pick a point $\omega$ on the sphere uniformly at random and consider the orthogonal projection of this point onto the north-south axis, then what is the probability that it is closer to the center of the sphere than it is from either pole?

First thing i want to make this question rigorous?
Thank you for any comments or hints.

Comment: Suppose $(X,Y,Z)\sim\mathcal{U}(\mathcal{S})$ where $\mathcal{S}=\{x^2+y^2+z^2=1\}\cap \mathbb{R}^3$. The orthogonal projection of $(X,Y,Z)$ onto the north$-$south axis is $(0,0,Z)$. The event that this projection is closer to the center of the sphere than it is to the poles is precisely the event that $\{|Z|<1/2\}$. Do you know how to continue?

Comment: @MatthewPilling thank you, I figured out that my aim is to calculate P{(x,y,z): x^2+y^2+z^2=1 & |z|<1/2}. Should i use Polar coordinates to find it?

Comment: I would use spherical coordinates. Up to you. Notice if $(X,Y,Z)\sim \mathcal{U}(\mathcal{S})$ then $f_{XYZ}(x,y,z)=\frac{1}{4\pi}$ whenever $(x,y,z)\in \mathcal{S}$ and $0$ elsewhere. To find $P(|Z|<1/2)$ you basically need to find the surface area of the portion of $\mathcal{S}$ residing in between the planes $z=-1/2,z=1/2$, then divide this result by $4\pi$.

Comment: In this way, I found $1/ \sqrt{2}$, but i didn't understand why i divide by $4\pi$. Can you explain this, thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm getting a probability of $1/2$. You divide by $4\pi$ since that's the surface area of a sphere. If you were instead sampling a point $(X,Y)$ uniformly from the unit disc $\mathbb{D}=\{x^2+y^2<1\}$ your density would be $f_{XY}(x,y)=\frac{1}{\pi}$ for $(x,y)\in \mathbb{D}$ and $f(x,y)=0$ elsewhere.

Comment: I made a mistake. Now, I got 1/2, thank you very much for your help.